# TFS 2010 Build Service

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2010

Consider a TFS 2010 server with "Build Service", "Build Controller" and "Build Agent" running on the same system. Things work 'most of the time', however occasionally I have to restart the 'Build Service'. Few questions:

1. What is the Build Service?
2. Do the build agents talk to anything other than the build controller (for example TFS)? I ask because I want to put the agents in another network which doesn't have access to TFS but a quick test shows that they are still looking for TFS, any ideas why?
3. My Build Service shows 3350 errors (!) in the last 24 hours. Looking at the event log I see a LOT of Controller or Agent "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildController\1\System.Core.dll'". Any ideas what its problem is? I can just feed it the files but I would like to know why it doesn't know where to find them.

Exact error from the event log:

> Service 'Default Agent - thakur' had an exception: Exception Message: Problem with loading custom assemblies: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\1\System.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type Exception) Exception Stack Trace:
>
> Service 'Default Controller - thakur' had an exception: Exception Message: Problem with loading custom assemblies: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildController\1\System.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type Exception) Exception Stack Trace:

There is nothing in the logs after 'Exception Stack Trace:'.

Comment: Can you supply a printout of the errors? Is your build controller setup correctly?

Comment: It is 'setup correctly' in the sense that I can execute workflows and get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review [Understanding a Team Foundation Build System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793166%28VS.100%29.aspx) and the first two questions should be answered.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The docs help but tfs still feels a little too opaque. Maybe I'll internalize it after a few more rounds of review.

Answer (score 1):

Does your "Build Agent" has .Net installed on it?

Comment: Yes -- it's actually my development machine with .NET 4 and VS 2010 installed.

Comment: build agent should preferably be a seperate build box, not your dev machine.